# trying to curl with a file into request and failing

Tags: linux, bash, curl

I'm trying to run weather data through `motion/motioneye`, and I've ran into a problem that I cannot for the life of me figure out.

I do this - and it works, embedding the text into the `image / timelapse`

```
$ curl http://192.168.0.168:7999/1/config/set?text_left="TESTING_PLEASE_STANDBY" text_left = TESTING_PLEASE_STANDBY Done
```

However my weather data is tagged out into a *file* - the inside looks like this:
`Temp: <#temp>°C - Press: <#press> hPa - Hum: <#hum>% - Wind: <#wspeed> mph(<#currentwdir>) - Rain: <#rfall> mm - UV Index: <#UV> - SolarRad: <#SolarRad> W/m² - CloudBase: <#cloudbase>`, which when processed is a text file that looks like this: `Temp: 7.2°C - Press: 973.9 hPa - Hum: 88% - Wind: 5 mph(SW) - Rain: 2.3 mm - UV Index: 0.0 - SolarRad: 0 W/m² - CloudBase: 759 ft`

It's just really a test at the moment but I just can't get motion to accept it regardless of how I try and there seems to be a lot of options as to how it can be done

```
curl --data "@Camdata.txt" http://192.168.0.168:7999/1/config/set?text_left

curl: (52) Empty reply from server

curl --data "@Camdata.txt" http://192.168.0.168:7999/1/config/set?text_left=

curl: (52) Empty reply from server

curl -d "$(Camdata.txt)" http://192.168.0.168:7999/1/config/set?text_left=

> -bash: Camdata.txt: command not found curl: (52) Empty reply from server

curl http://192.168.0.168:7999/1/config/set?text_left="TESTING_PLEASE_STANDBY" text_left = TESTING_PLEASE_STANDBY Done
```

I would be very grateful for any assistance.

I have also been given this bit of code, - they use it with rest.api - but all I want to do is read a series of values into a variable - and then push that variable as a string of text into motion:

```
TEXTLEFT=`curl --insecure --silent http://localhost:8181/weather/api/realtime/latest/metar`
TEXTLEFT="${TEXTLEFT// /%20}" #Replace spaces with %20
curl --silent "http://localhost:8080/101/config/set%3Ftext_left=$TEXTLEFT"
```

Again, I already have a **Camdata.txt** resource file that's produced locally, so I don't need to pull it from somewhere else - I just need to *find a way* to get **Camdata.txt** into `TEXTLEFT` and then use push `TEXTLEFT` into request. Totally driving me nuts and up until now, the most I've done with `curl` is install *pihole*!